# import user contacts form google, yahoo, and AOL in php

Tags: php

I search through the internet around whole week but could not find a good resources to import user contacts form google, yahoo, and AOL like main mail accounts. Actually I am expecting a php implementation to do this. when I search I found some people have suggested third party app. But here I am looking for some my own app for import users contact book. Please any one can help me to do this or give me some idea to that.

Comment: Go through that open source third party tools and find how they did it? Read their code and get ideas from them.

Answer (score 2):

You access the contacts data through APIs:

http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/

http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/

AOL does not have one currently

If you want a paid solution (that does all three) there is CloudSponge: http://www.cloudsponge.com/

Comment: Now I am ok with google and yahoo. I bloged at source code at www.anandafit.info. But still could not find a good solution for AOL.

Comment: I found this (http://dev.aol.com/api/openauth) for AOL and hope that here PHP code sample need to be work. But I could not success it yet. when I try this code and finally it gave fallowing result.        {"response":{"statusCode":443, "statusText":"Key Used From unauthenticated site.  statusDetailCode 1004", "statusDetailCode":1004, "data":{}}}